# Парсинг данных с HH: ошибка R

Tags: json, парсер, r

Моя задача спарсить больше 2000 вакансий с hh. Когда я задаю параметр `for (pageNum in 0:1000)`, выдает ошибку *Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : HTTP error 400*

Как можно решить данную проблему? Что означает эта ошибка? Может быть есть вариант по-другому скачать больше 2000 вакансий?

```
  Name = character(),  # Название компании
  Name = character(), # Название вакансии
  Currency = character(), # Валюта
  From = character(), # Минимальная оплата
  Area = character(), # Город
  Requerement = character(), # Требуемые навыки
  responsibility = character(), 
  stringsAsFactors = T) 
  
  for (pageNum in 0:1000) { # Всего страниц
  data <- fromJSON(paste0("https://api.hh.ru/vacancies?text=\"'HR\"&page=", pageNum))
  vacanciesdf <- rbind(vacanciesdf, data.frame(
    data$items$area$name, # Город
    data$items$salary$currency, # Валюта
    data$items$salary$from, # Минимальная оплата
    data$items$employer$name, # Название компании
    data$items$snippet$requirement,# Требуемые навыки
    data$items$snippet$responsibility,
    data$items$name))
  print(paste0("Upload pages:", pageNum + 1))
  Sys.sleep(3)}
```

Comment: [_HTTP error 400_](https://http.cat/400) - плохой запрос

Comment: [1. Порядок начала использования Сервиса

1.1. Для начала использования Сервиса Разработчику приложения посредством своей учетной информации на Сайте необходимо пройти процедуру регистрации программы для ЭВМ, которая будет в последующем взаимодействовать (использовать API) с Сервисом на программном уровне (далее– «Приложение») на Сайте по адресу https://dev.hh.ru и получить уникальный API-ключ.](https://dev.hh.ru/admin/developer_agreement)

Comment: ха. [один и тот же код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Requerement) годами копи-пастится, видимо, в надежде, что на hh отменят все изменения, произошедшие за эти годы, и написанный когда-то код снова заработает.

Answer (score 0):

как раз сейчас парсим..

```
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
library(RCurl)

setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path)); getwd(); gc()
options(scipen = 999)

start <- 40035001
end <- 40040000

time_start <- Sys.time()
t <- data.frame() 
for (vac_number in c(start:end)) {
  t_1 <- data.frame(vacancy = vac_number, 
                    is_exist = url.exists(paste0('https://hh.kz/vacancy/', vac_number)))
  t <- rbind(t, t_1)
  message(vac_number)
}
time_end <- Sys.time()



d <- t %>% dplyr::filter(is_exist == TRUE)

time_start_1 <- Sys.time()
for (vac_number in d$vacancy) {
  vacancy <- xml2::read_html(paste0('https://hh.kz/vacancy/', vac_number))
  write_xml(vacancy, file = paste0(vac_number, ".html"))
  message(vac_number)
  }
time_end_2 <- Sys.time()
message(time_end-time_start)
message(time_end_2-time_start_1)
```

получается небыстро, по одной вакансии в секунду примерно. зато потом можно разобрать скачанные html-ки как уже удобно. обратите внимание, что архивные вакансии при этом у меня вылезли в unicode, и пришлось помучаться, чтобы вытащить необходимое

```
library(qdapRegex)
options(scipen = 999)

setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path)); getwd(); gc()


vacancy_id <- 40000000

vacancy <- readLines(paste0(vacancy_id, '.html'), encoding = 'UTF-8') %>% as.data.frame()

title_1 <- vacancy[grep("vacancy-title__archived-from", vacancy$.), ]

title_start <- '<h1 data-qa="vacancy-title" class="bloko-header-1">'
title_end <- '<div class="vacancy-title__archived-from">'

title <- rm_between(title_1, title_start, title_end, extract = TRUE)[[1]]

skill_1 <- vacancy[grep('"keySkills": \\{"keySkill": \\[', vacancy$.), ]
skill_start <- '"keySkill": ["'
skill_end <- ']}, "driverLicenseTypes"'

s_1 <- rm_between(skill_1, skill_start, skill_end, extract = TRUE)[[1]] 
s_2 <- stringi::stri_unescape_unicode(s_1)

place_1 <- vacancy[grep('"addressLocality"', vacancy$.), ] %>% 
  str_replace('"addressLocality":', '') %>% trimws() %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
  `colnames<-`('addressLocality')

place_2 <- vacancy[grep('"addressRegion"', vacancy$.), ] %>% 
  str_replace('"addressRegion":', '') %>% trimws() %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
  `colnames<-`('addressRegion')

place_3 <- vacancy[grep('"addressCountry"', vacancy$.), ] %>% 
  str_replace('"addressCountry":', '') %>% trimws() %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
  `colnames<-`('addressCountry')

total <- data.frame(id = vacancy_id, title = title, key_skill = s_2)
```